# Rails Capistrano Authentication fail error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ssh, puma

I'm following a [tutorial](https://ogdenstudios.xyz/blog/how-do-i-deploy-a-rails-6-app-to-amazon-ec-2/) to host my Rails 6 application on AWS using `Capistrano3`, `Puma` web server and `nginx`. I am in the final stages, but keep getting an **Authentication failed** error when I try to deploy my Ruby on Rails application using Capistrano. The command I am using is `cap production deploy`. I created a ssh key pair, added the public key to my Github repo containing the application code, and added the private key file path to the below snippet in the file: `/Users/edward/Project/EdwardBlog/blog/config/deploy/production.rb`

```
set :ssh_options, { 
  forward_agent: true, 
  auth_methods: %w[publickey],
  keys: %w[/Users/edward/.ssh/id_rsa]
}
```

I can ssh into github like so `ssh -T git@github.com` and I double checked the key pair matches the public SSH key I added to my github account. I also added the private key to ssh-agent using `ssh-add -l`

I also tried to deploy the app using my password, but still had no luck when I entered my github account password at the prompt:

```
set :ssh_options, {
   keys: %w(/Users/edward/.ssh/id_rsa),
   forward_agent: true,
   auth_methods: %w(password)
 }
```

I don't know why it's not authenticating using the credentials locally. Would appreciate any possible solutions or workarounds.

Here is my message when running the command cap production deploy --trace:

```
#<Thread:0x00007f9b70963d00@/Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    12: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    11: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    10: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
     9: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.2/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
     8: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
     7: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
     6: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
     5: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
     4: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:130:in `execute_command'
     3: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:177:in `with_ssh'
     2: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `with'
     1: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `call'
/Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:263:in `start': Authentication failed for user ubuntu@18.191.247.244 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed)
    1: from /Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/edward/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.20.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as ubuntu@18.191.247.244: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@18.191.247.244 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@18.191.247.244: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@18.191.247.244


Caused by:
Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@18.191.247.244

Tasks: TOP => deploy:check => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as ubuntu@18.191.247.244: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@18.191.247.244


** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:


Please make sure you have the correct access rights

and the repository exists.

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO START 2020-01-01 13:58:01 -0800 cap production deploy

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO rbenv: rbenv_ruby is not set; ruby version will be defined by the remote hosts via rbenv

  INFO [ca90e3ef] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp as ubuntu@18.191.247.244

 DEBUG [ca90e3ef] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp )

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO START 2020-01-01 13:58:35 -0800 cap production deploy

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO rbenv: rbenv_ruby is not set; ruby version will be defined by the remote hosts via rbenv

  INFO [cd0c878a] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp as ubuntu@18.191.247.244

 DEBUG [cd0c878a] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp )

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO START 2020-01-01 14:28:49 -0800 cap production deploy

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  INFO rbenv: rbenv_ruby is not set; ruby version will be defined by the remote hosts via rbenv

  INFO [a745cde8] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp as ubuntu@18.191.247.244

 DEBUG [a745cde8] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Authentication failed for user ubuntu@18.191.247.244

This issue is in shelling into your deploy target as `ubuntu`, it's not in the connection to Github. Make sure that you can shell into that IP with the `ubuntu` user, and if so, try adding your SSH key to your agent (`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` or whatever) to ensure that Capistrano can establish an SSH connection to your deploy target machine.

Comment: how would i go about shelling into the ip as ubuntu user? sorry for my ignorance, I think I am missing the bigger picture here. I thought `cap production deploy` would clone my project to the server using the same authentication i have locally.

Comment: `ssh -v ubuntu@18.191.247.244` will do it. The `-v` will show you which key it's using, if it succeeds. Be sure that key is added to your ssh agent. cap will use your local credentials, but it may not be able to find them in some cases, and you may have to help it by adding them to the agent.

Comment: i am able to connect to 18.191.247.244, but am unable to authenticate: `Permissions denied (publickey)` message. Do I need to copy over my key on local machine to the server?

Comment: Yes. You will need to install your pubkey into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the target server, or you will need to use a privkey that already has a pubkey installed.

Comment: thanks. I realized I needed to send github private key and server  private key to deploy target. So my `production.rb` file ended up looking like this:  `set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, 
  auth_methods: %w[publickey],
  keys: %w[/Users/edward/Desktop/KEYS/blog/blog-key-pair.pem]
}
set :ssh_options, { 
  forward_agent: true, 
  auth_methods: %w[publickey],
  keys: %w[/Users/edward/.ssh/id_rsa]
}`